# Tool for packing css files as JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for an external tool for creating valid JavaScript strings from a css file.

The content of the css file should be well escaped and compressed (if possible) into a JavaScript string.

The reason for that is, that I'd like to deliver my library only in one file, the JavaScript file. Consider, this cannot (?) be done with the common webassets/packaging/compressing tools.

Any ideas? Best regards.

Comment: Not entirely sure this is a good idea at all...which is why its not part of common webassets/packaging/compressing tools

Comment: If it is a library you are making wouldn't you want people to be able to easily modify the css to their needs? This would make it very difficult on people trying to use your library.

Comment: The css is not intended to be part of a "public interface" of the component. It shouldn't be overwritten by the user. Actually that's not a simple component, it's part of a bigger cloudservice (like google maps), therefore the interface should be as simple as possible. To reach as many users (webdevelopers) as possible, one has to include only one file into the webpage.

Comment: One simple solution could be to pack the content of the css file as base64 string with an external tool and to use atob() in javascript to decode it. But the encoded string (the output) is 133% of the input. I prefer a simpler, escaping solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question.

The (NodeJS-) projects https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css and https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc fits the requirements.

Usage:

```
cleancss input.css -o input.min.css
jsesc < input.min.css > output.txt
```

The *output.txt* file contains the well escaped JavaScript string.